# Can't get value of system environment variable in batch script for task scheduler

Tags: svn

I'm trying to set up a batch script for the task scheduler to perform incremental dumps of a svn repository. For that I would like to save the latest revision of the repo for the next execution of the script in a system environment variable, something like this:

```
@setlocal
@echo off
:: Get value from last execution
set LAST_REV=%SVN_LAST_BACKUP_REV%
set /a OLDEST=%LAST_REV%+1
for /F "tokens=*" %%g in ('svnlook youngest %REPO_DIR%') do (SET YOUNGEST=%%g)

svnadmin dump repo -r %OLDEST%:%YOUNGEST% --incremental > backup/repo.dump

:: Save youngest rev for next execution
setx SVN_LAST_BACKUP_REV %YOUNGEST%
```

Somehow `%SVN_LAST_BACKUP_REV%` is not defined (I added a line `if not defined SVN_LAST_BACKUP_REV echo sadface`) even though setting a value with `setx` did work and it does show up with a value when i check manually in the system properties.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have not provided sufficient information regarding the configuration settings of your scheduled task. Currently your `setx` command does not specifiy that the variable should be set in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, i.e. system wide, so it would be set to the default, under the HKEY_CURRENT_USER environment. Without therefore knowing under which user context your task is being run, we cannot determine which users registry it is trying to add your variable and value to.

Comment: `setx` does not set a variable in the current `cmd` session, you will need `set` for that…

Comment: @Compo I tried to debug by manually executing the batch. Shouln't that mean, that even if it gets saved to HKEY_CURRENT_USER environment, that a subsequent execution should provide access to the previously saved variable?

Comment: @aschipfl I don't need it in the current session, I want a variable that can be accessed at the next execution of the script without using temp files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error with the way I was working with Notepad++:
Rightclicking the tab with the batch document you get the option to "Open Containing Folder in cmd" which is how I tried to debug above code:

[image: Notepad++ rightclick menu screenshot]

I didn't know that closing the cmd and reopening the cmd this way from Notepad++ does NOT change the context of it, therefore the environment variable was still not visible.
This was resolved when I restarted Notepad++, now I know that I need to (re-)open cmd the usual way to get a new session.